# Strip a IPTC.php result into two variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, iptc

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    require_once('IPTC.php');
    $iptc = new Image_IPTC('001.jpg');
    print_r($iptc);
?>
```

And it returns:

> Image_IPTC Object ( [_sFilename] => 001.jpg [_aIPTC] => Array (
>   [1#090] => Array ( [0] => %G ) [2#000] => Array ( [0] =>  ) [2#005]
>   => Array ( [0] => TITULO NO WINDOWS, TITLE NO BRIDGE ) [2#080] => Array ( [0] => pictureauthor ) [2#085] => Array ( [0] => photographer )
>   [2#090] => Array ( [0] => mycity ) [2#095] => Array ( [0] => ST )
>   [2#101] => Array ( [0] => mycountry ) [2#105] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IWANTTHIS1 ) [2#116] => Array ( [0] => copyrightinfo ) [2#120] => Array ( [0] => IWANTTHIS2 ) ) [_bIPTCParse] => 1
>   )

This is a dummy question, but how do I put texts "IWANTTHIS1" and "IWANTTHIS2" into 2 different variables to use like this:

```
echo "title: $variable1 <br />";
echo "descr: $variable2";
```

Resulting in:

```
title: IWANTTHIS1
descr: IWANTTHIS2
```

I'm pretty shure it's extremelly easy for you guys, but I'm still learning all this. I think it's an array inside an array? Can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$variable1 = $iptc->_aIPTC['2#105'][0]; 
$variable2 = $iptc->_aIPTC['2#120'][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Rodaine's answer was giving me "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Image_IPTC as array". With some research, the final correct answer is:

```
$variable1 = $iptc->_aIPTC['2#105'][0];
$variable2 = $iptc->_aIPTC['2#120'][0];
```

I wouldn't be able to achieve it by myself at all, therefore I'm marking Rodaine's answer as correct.

Thank you very much.